# R, combine vectors having sequential names

Tags: r, vector, stack

I want to stack the vectors having sequential names.

For example, I have

```
a1<-1:3
a2<-4:6
a3<-7:9
```

I know that I could you

```
z<-as.vector(rbind(a1,a2,a3))
```

How can I do this if I have 100 of as, a1 ,a2, a3, ..., a100?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the variables using `get()`.
Your example would then look as follows:

```
a_list <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
    a_list[[i]] <- get(paste0("a",i))
}

z <- as.vector(do.call("rbind",a_list))
```

Or using `lapply`:

```
as.vector(do.call("rbind",lapply(1:3,function(x){get(paste0("a",x))})))
```

You could then do this e.g. for `i in 1:100` or whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mget`. The following results the same output as your exmple code. You can then change `1:3` to `1:100`.

```
as.vector(matrix(unlist(mget(paste0("a", 1:3))), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know`mget`.

Answer (score 0):

If you had them all as members of a list 'lst' , then you could simply call do.call(rbind,lst), or do.call(c, lst) - or even unlist(lst).  So the trick is to get the variables into a list.  You can do this by using 'ls' to return the names of variables you want, and then use mget on those names:

do.call(c, mget(ls(pattern="a[0-9]+")))

where the pattern is a regular expression that finds all variables of the form a123 in your global environment.

Comment: Thank you..when I do this, 'what' must be a function or character string, message came out. can you help me a little more?

Comment: 'c' is normally a function, so you may have redefined it?  Try do.call(rbind, ...) and see if that works better.